# How to extract value from xml field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have field with a xml, something like this:

```
<ApplicationProductFields>
  <string>
    <field name="Tech_LoginUzytkownika">lechowski</field>
  </string>
  <int />
  <decimal />
  <bool />
  <datetime />
  <appendix />
  <enum />
  <complex>
    <field name="danePrzesylki">
      <fv>
        <rodzajPrzesylki>sPP</rodzajPrzesylki>
        <dataWplywu>d08/24/2016 00:00:00</dataWplywu>
        <nadawcaNazwisko>sKowalski</nadawcaNazwisko>
        <dokumenty>
          <tytulDokumentu>sDokument testowy 45</tytulDokumentu>
          <dataUtworzenia>d2016-06-13 00:00:00</dataUtworzenia>
```

I need to insert all values in different table fields, ex.

```
|rodzajPrzesylki|     dataWplywu     |nadawcaNazwisko|  tytulDokumentu  |...
|      sPP      |d08/24/2016 00:00:00|   sKowalski   |sDokument testowy |...
```

I found sql query this sql query:

```
SELECT 
col.value('(/ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString/EntityPropertyOfString[Name="Profit Center"]/Value)[1]', 'int')
FROM tbl
```

But I don't know how to use it with my xml construction.

Anyone help my ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this XML and its generation is under your control, you should think about it:

1. The XML was not generated properly. Date/Time values within XML should follow `ISO8601`... You'll have to convert them manually.
2. I think, that the first letter ("sPP" or "d08/24...") is kind of a datatype mark (string and date), which is very unprofessional... If you'd want to mark this, better use type attributes or a schema...

The XML you provide is not complete (I had to close the XML with some tags), neither did you show the target table's structure.
Anyhow: The first thing to do is to shredd the XML. This will create a *derived table*. In my example I'll use a `CTE` to provide this table for a `SELECT` statement. At the end you see `SELECT * FROM CTE;`. This will offer the resultset as if  it would be taken from an ordinary table:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<ApplicationProductFields>
  <string>
    <field name="Tech_LoginUzytkownika">lechowski</field>
  </string>
  <int />
  <decimal />
  <bool />
  <datetime />
  <appendix />
  <enum />
  <complex>
    <field name="danePrzesylki">
      <fv>
        <rodzajPrzesylki>sPP</rodzajPrzesylki>
        <dataWplywu>d08/24/2016 00:00:00</dataWplywu>
        <nadawcaNazwisko>sKowalski</nadawcaNazwisko>
        <dokumenty>
          <tytulDokumentu>sDokument testowy 45</tytulDokumentu>
          <dataUtworzenia>d2016-06-13 00:00:00</dataUtworzenia>
        </dokumenty>
      </fv>
    </field>
  </complex>
</ApplicationProductFields>';
```

--The query

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT fld.value(N'@name','nvarchar(max)') AS FieldName
          ,fld.value(N'(fv/rodzajPrzesylki)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS rodzajPrzesylki
          ,fld.value(N'(fv/dataWplywu)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS dataWplywu
          ,fld.value(N'(fv/nadawcaNazwisko)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS nadawcaNazwisko
          ,fld.value(N'(fv/dokumenty/tytulDokumentu)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS tytulDokumentu
          ,fld.value(N'(fv/dokumenty/dataUtworzenia)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS dataUtworzenia
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/ApplicationProductFields/complex/field') AS A(fld)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Just put something there like

```
INSERT INTO MyTargetTable(FieldName, rodarodzajPrzesylki, ...)
SELECT FieldName,rodzajPrzesylki,... 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've found is an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). This query language operating on XML has a rather simple syntax, where you describe the path needed to access a node from an XML document. It is [defined by the w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), and the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) does a pretty good job of documenting it in a more accessible way.

I'll let you check the documentation and give you an example of XPath for your `rodzajPrzesylki` field :

```
/ApplicationProductFields/complex/field[name="danePrzesylki"]/fv/rodzajPrzesylki
```